# Reactions involving trimethylaluminium Al2Me6

Tags: stoichiometry

I need to write balanced equations describing the following reactions:

- one mole of $\ce{Al2Me6}$ with two moles of water
- excess of $\ce{Al2Me6}$ with silicon dioxide
- excess of $\ce{Al2Me6}$ with tin(IV) chloride

My answer so far:

- a) $\ce{2H2O + Al2Me6 -> Al2Me4(H2O)2}$?
- b) $\ce{SiO2 + Al2Me6 -> SiMe4 + Al2Me2O2}$?
- c) $\ce{SnCl4 + Al2Me6 -> SnMe4 + Al2Me2Cl4}$?

Comment: Organoaluminium compounds are very reactive. If a substance is capable of attacking one of the methyl groups in trimethylaluminium, then the process likely doesn't stop until *all* carbon-aluminium bonds are broken. Can you figure out the answer now?

Comment: Balance your equations.  Draw structures to see what is happening.  Why is trimethylaluminum dimeric?  For (a), what happens when you mix a Bronsted acid with a Bronsted base given a potent oxophile?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's an AMIRITE question unlikely to be of help to future visitors.

Answer (score 3):

For a): Many organometallic compounds are easily hydrolyzed to the respective hydrocarbons and metal (hydr)oxides. In this case, the products are $\ce{CH4}$ and more likely $\ce{Al2O3}$, because the formation of $\ce{Al(OH)3}$ requires more moles of water.

Reactions b) and c) should be transmetallations where the methyl groups are transferred from aluminium to the other metal. The excess of $\ce{Al2Me6}$ helps to shift the equilibrium of the reaction to the product side. $\ce{SiMe4}$ and $\ce{SnMe4}$ would be the correct products which you have identified, but aluminium is also converted into its respective oxide/chloride.